# play! bundle for textmate is giving me errors

Tags: playframework, textmatebundles

I'm trying to configure textmate with Play! and I keep getting this error when I use the model shortcut

/Users/bennett/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Pristine Copy/Bundles/Play!.tmbundle/Support/bin/model.py: Permission denied

Can anyone make heads or tails of this? some of the other short cuts work. Just not model or class.

Answer (score 1):

If that can help I had the same issue and fixed it by :

1. Renaming `Play!.tmbundle` to `Play!.zip` (within `/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Pristine Copy/Bundles/`)
2. Adding the execution rights (744) to the python scripts : `Support/bin/*.py`
3. Renaming back `Play!.zip` to `Play!.tmbundle`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it as following:

```
chmod -R +x /Users/**YOURUSERNAMEHERE**/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Pristine Copy/Bundles/Play!.tmbundle/Support/bin
```

Comment: I get an error when I do this. **-bash: !.tmbundle/Support/bin: event not found**

Answer (score 1):

Just escape the special chars:

```
chmod +x /Users/<username>/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Pristine\ Copy/Bundles/Play\!.tmbundle/Support/bin/*.py
```

Answer (score 0):

it seams to be a bug. I recommend you to create a ticket here : http://play.lighthouseapp.com/dashboard